# How to add spacing between lines css

Tags: html, css, inline

How do I add spacing between the drop down boxes in the aside so they are in line with the questions in my section?

```css
select {
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

section {
  width: 31%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 270px;
}

aside {
  width: 31%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 270px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Children's Quiz</h1>
  <img src="childrenfun.webp" alt="child" height=300 width=600>
</header>

<section>

  <p>What colour is made from yellow and red?</p>

  <p>How many fingers do humans have?</p>

  <p>What is 20 + 4?</p>

</section>

<aside>
  <select id="q1">
    <option>White
      <option>Yellow
        <option value="correct">Orange
          <option>Green
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="q2">
    <option value="correct">10
      <option>20
        <option>5
          <option>8
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="q3">
    <option>21
      <option>6
        <option>204
          <option value="correct">24
  </select>
</aside>

<article>
  <button id="checkButton">Check Answers</button>
</article>
```

This is what my website looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: Ideally questions and answers would be in the same container, forming rows. You also wouldn't use ´<BR>´ ... and many other things. I think you need to fix you HTML before anything

Comment: to eleborate @LaurentS. comment: You have an invalid HTML markup. You never close your `<option>` tag. Then `<br>` adds a line break, not a gap between lines. For that you either use `margins/paddings` or `line-height` depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally questions and answers would be in the same container, forming rows.

To keep the questions and drop down boxes in line a good solution would be to put them in the same container in your html code: `<div class="box"></div>`. Now you got two items (questions and drop down boxes) inside those containers.

In your css code [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will allow you to keep your question and drop down boxes in the same row `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` , and to vertically align those items `align-items: center;`.

```css
  .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .box p {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .box div {
    width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p>What colour is made from yellow and red?</p>
    <div>
        <select id="q1">
            <option>White</option>
            <option>Yellow</option>
            <option value="correct">Orange</option>
            <option>Green</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>How many fingers do humans have?</p>
    <div>
        <select id="q2">
            <option value="correct">10</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>8</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>What is 20 + 4?</p>
    <div>
        <select id="q3">
            <option>21</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>204</option>
            <option value="correct">24</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **down-voted for following reason:** Your explaination is to insufficient for me. If I would be the OP, I wouldnt find it useable as I wont udnerstand your answer and therefor be unable to reproduce it. Last but not least you maintained the invalid HTML markup. This should have been addressed and fixed aswell.